# Best method to store in python

Tags: python

```
a=[]
n=['1','2','3','4','5']
#initialization  
for i in n:
    a[i]={'acctd' : '0',
          'authd' : '0',
          'aggregator' :  '0',
          'sh' : '0'
         }
#printing the data
for i in n:
    print a[i]
```

## Traceback (most recent call last):

File "myarray.py", line 8, in 
    'sh' : '0'
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve over here? Please explain as your question is highly unclear

Comment: Your error is because `n` is full of strings not numbers (because you quoted the numbers)

Comment: Why are you quoting all your numbers, in both the list and the dictionary?

Comment: I need your story more... but to simply talk about the traceback, it should be `a[1]`, not `a['1']`, as described in the `TypeError` message.

Comment: Either change your list to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` or use `a[int(i)] = ...`

Comment: I have to initialize multiple dictionary @M

Comment: @SumitkSuman, you are using string as index

Comment: Also, Python doesn't allow you to assign to list indexes that don't exist yet. You need to use `a.append({...})`

Comment: Or you should make `a` a dictionary instead of a list4.

Comment: @SumitkSuman List in python do not work the way you think it does. Please refer the linked question to know about it. You should also see the python tutorial. You should be using `list.append(..)` method to add item to list

Comment: yup i have try ,if i remove then also it does not affect and my story is :i want to initialize multiple dictionary(e.g:a[1]={'apple':0,'boy':0}) like that @leo

Comment: Thank you @MoinuddinQuadri i will try but i have to do like that yup i am going through python tutorial

Comment: yep the tagged answer would be really helpful:)

Comment: Tahnks all i got what i want to do